# Radio buttons not working / selectable in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, radio-button

I have a couple of radio buttons, which are working absolutely fine in Chrome, Firefox and Safari, but when using Internet Explorer (Version 7) they're just not selectable. Any ideas how I could fix this?

HTML:

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="12" value="1">
    <span>12</span>
</label>
```

CSS:

```
label input[type=radio]{ position: absolute; top: -20px; }
input[type=radio]:checked + span{ color: #fff; background: #8dc63f; }
```

Comment: I see. You're not saying that they're not selectable; sounds like what you mean is that they don't *show* as selected with that CSS style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS 2.1 selectors + is not availbale in IE 7

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2

Answer (score 1):

Some IE versions can't parse this CSS selector:

```
input[type=radio]:checked + span
```

If you really need to have that behavior you will have to use Javascript to do those style changes when `input[type=radio]` `change` event is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

The `:checked` selector is available on IE9+ (Source: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a DIV instead of a label